# Implementing MVC pattern in SWT application

Tags: java, design-patterns, eclipse

I am developing an SWT application (it's basically an Eclipse plugin, so I need to use SWT). Currently my design is as follows:

- Model: In model, I have POJOs which represents the actual fields in views.
- View: It is a dumb layer, it contains just UI and contains no logic (not even event handlers)
- Controller: It acts as a mediator b/w those two layers. Also it is responsible for creating view layer, handling events etc.

Basically I have created all of the controls in view as a static like this `public static Button btnLogin` and in controller I have a code like this:

```
public void createLoginView(Composite comp) {
    LoginFormView.createView(comp);  //This createView method is in view layer ie LoginFormView
    LoginFormView.btnLogin.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        //Code goes here
    });  
}
```

Similalrly I have done for other views and controls. So that in main class and other classes I am calling just `createLoginView` of controller. I am doing similar thing for other views.

So my question, is what I am doing is correct? Is this design good? Or I should have followed any other approach. Since I am new to SWT and Eclipse plugin development (basically I am Java EE developer having 4+ years of exp). Any tips/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The MVC Design Pattern that you implemented is definitely good, but I would also encourage you to implement the OOPs in it. It would only then serve your purpose better.

Here are few links, which should help you understand it better;

1. [N-Layer Architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/128812/n-layers-architecture-design-really-worth-the-effort)
2. [OOPS](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95499/object-oriented-class-design)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have [the eclipse plugin development guide](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/firstplugin.htm) at hand, it does not mention any specific design you should/could follow so I guess as long it it gets the job done. it's good.

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't, I like to differ with your answer, generally these design are for future maintenance of the software.

Comment: Yes, Your MVC style is good. It enables future maintenance to be easy as well as, additional functionality to be added with ease. So overall the design is a good.